# LoadLibrary returning Null

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, loadlibrary

I just tried the following code(windows xp sp3, vs2010) and LoadLibrary seems to be returning Null.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    HMODULE hNtdll;
    hNtdll = LoadLibrary(LPCWSTR("ntdll.dll"));
    printf("%08x\n", hNtdll);
}
```

The output I get is `00000000`. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), NULL is returned when the function fails. I tried using `GetLastError` and the error code is 126([0x7e, Error Mod Not Found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

How can I correct this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a string literal, which consists of narrow characters. Your `LoadLibrary` call apparently expects wide characters. Type-casting isn't the way to convert from one to the other. Use the `L` prefix to get a wide string literal:

```
LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll")
```

Type-casting tells the compiler that your `char const*` is really a `wchar_t const*`, which isn't true. The compiler trusts you and passes the pointer along to `LoadLibrary` anyway, but when interpreted as a wide string, the thing you passed is nonsense. It doesn't represent the name of any file on your system, so the API correctly reports that it cannot find the module.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `LoadLibrary(_T("ntdll.dll"))` LPCWSTR just casts char-based string pointer to widestring pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the necessity of converting the path `string` to `wchar_t const*` by using `L` prefix (which is already mentioned in the accepted answer). According to my last couple of hours experience:
it worths mentioning that `LoadLibrary` function does not load the dependency(ies) of the intended library (DLL) automatically. In other word, if you try to load the library X which depends on the library Y, you should do `LoadLibrary(Y)`, then `LoadLibrary(X)`, otherwise loading the library X will fail and you will get error `126`.